# Solaris services type status

Tags: service, solaris, solaris-10

There are following service states in Solaris:

> 1. degraded – The instance is running or available to run, but is functioning at a limited capacity.
> 2. disabled – The instance is not enabled and is not running or available to run.
> 3. maintenance – The instance is enabled but not able to run. The instance might be transitioning through the maintenance state because
>      an administrative action has not yet completed. Otherwise,
>      administrative action is required to resolve the problem.
> 4. offline – The instance is enabled but not running or available to run. For example, if the dependencies of an enabled service are not
>      satisfied, the service is kept in the offline state.
> 5. online – The instance is enabled and running or available to run. The online state is the expected operating state for a correctly
>      configured service instance with all dependencies satisfied.
> 6. uninitialized – This state is the initial state for all services.

I want to understand the 'uninitialized' state. Someone, please explain this state. Does this mean that the service is installed and enabled but it is not yet enabled. Or the service is in disabled state.

Comment: Ask this question here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

This is the usual state when you clear the service status after `maintenance`. [Here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E88353_01/html/E37853/smf-7.html#REFMAN7smf-7) you can find more explanations.

> UNINITIALIZED
>
> This state is the initial state for all service instances, including newly created instances (through executing svccfg add,
>   importing a manifest, or applying a profile). When an instance is
>   cleared from the maintenance state (svcadm clear), it is placed in the
>   uninitialized state so that its restarter can re-evaluate its
>   configuration. Instances are moved to maintenance, offline, or
>   disabled state after evaluation by the appropriate restarter. Note
>   that evaluation of an instance can only occur if its restarter service
>   is online.